# Missing library when using Google drive sdk - Xcode 5, iOS7

Tags: objective-c, google-drive-api

I followed the examples as well as watched the video. I have added the GTL project correctly. When I add the libGTLTouchStaticLib.a, it says it is missing. However, when I run it in the simulator, it is fine.

Is this a known issue with Xcode 5, iOS7?

Comment: did u get solution or not

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not an issue with Xcode 7 and iOS7. The thing is that `libGTLTouchStaticLib.a` will be automatically added when u add GTL project.